# VMware ESXi 4.1: how to create a new user with root permissions

Tags: ssh, vmware-esxi, user-permissions

In ESXi 4.1, I have SSH access enabled and a user jdoe, who is able to connect to the system via ssh.

~ $ less /etc/passwd | grep jdoe
jdoe:x:3:0:John Doe:/home/jdoe:/bin/ash

The user jdoe has all permissions I managed to provide: 0 for GUID, and Administrator rights in vSphere client (Permissions tab). Nevertheless, this user doesn't have root permissions. For instance, under jdoe login, I can't change a password for another user:

~ $ passwd user27
passwd: jdoe can't change password for user27

My question is: how to provide a user jdoe with all permissions root has?

Some comments: I need it to keep root away from day-to-day operations. Also, for some reason , su or sudo is not the option.

Comment: If you want to keep root away from day-to-day operations, then how does creating an exact copy of the root account help?  Aren't you just making it twice as easy to compromise the root privileges since two accounts will have them instead of one?

Comment: ESXi isn't built to be managed from the command line..

Comment: root is not auditable thus he's creating a seperate account. Also Shane Madden is right stop using the cli on esxi.